# Python: Iterate over dataframes of different lengths, and compute new value with repeat values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, iteration

EDIT:
I realized I set up my example incorrectly, the corrected version follows:

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x values': [11, 12, 13], 'time':[1,2.2,3.5})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x values': [11, 21, 12, 43], 'time':[1,2.1,2.6,3.1})
```

What I need to do is iterate over both of these dataframes, and compute a new value, which is a ratio of the x values in df1 and df2. The difficulty comes in because these dataframes are of different lengths.

If I just wanted to compute values in the two, I know that I could use something like zip, or even map. Unfortunately, I don't want to drop any values. Instead, I need to be able to compare the time column between the two frames to determine whether or not to copy over a value from a previous time to the computation of in the next time period.

So for instance, I would compute the first ratio:

```
df1["x values"][0]/df2["x values"][0]
```

Then for the second I check which update happens next, which in this case is to df2, so df1["time"] < df2["time"] and:

```
df1["x values"][0]/df2["x values"][1]
```

For the third I would see that df1["time"] > df2["time"], so the third computation would be:

```
df1["x values"][1]/df2["x values"][1]
```

The only time both values should be used to compute the ratio from the same "position" is if the times in the two dataframes are equal.

And so on. I'm very confused as to whether or not this is possible to execute using something like a lambda function, or itertools. I've made some attempts, but most have yielded errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. Hopefully it helps clarify what my question was. Also, if anyone can think of a more pythonic way to do this, I would appreciate the feedback.

```
 #add a column indicating which 'type' of dataframe it is
 df1['type']=pd.Series('type1',index=df1.index)
 df2['type']=pd.Series('type2',index=df2.index)

 #concatenate the dataframes
 df = pd.concat((df1, df2),axis=0, ignore_index=True)

 #sort by time
 df = df.sort_values(by='time').reset_index()

 #we create empty arrays in order to track records
 #in a way that will let us compute ratios
 x1 = []
 x2 = []

 #we will iterate through the dataframe line by line
 for i in range(0,len(df)):

     #if the row contains data from df1
     if df["type"][i] == "type1":

         #we append the x value for that type
         x1.append(df[df["type"]=="type1"]["x values"][i])

         #if the x2 array contains exactly 1 value
         if len(x2) == 1:
              #we add it to match the number of x1
              #that we have recorded up to that point
              #this is useful if one time starts before the other
              for j in range(1, len(x1)-1):  
                  x2.append(x2[0])

         #if the x2 array contains more than 1 value
         #add a copy of the previous x2 record to correspond
         #to the new x1 record
         if len(x2) > 0:
              x2.append(x2[len(x2)-1])

    #if the row contains data from df2

    if df["type"][i] == "type2":

         #we append the x value for that type
         x2.append(df[df["type"]=="type2"]["x values"][i])

         #if the x1 array contains exactly 1 value
         if len(x1) == 1:
              #we add it to match the number of x2
              #that we have recorded up to that point
              #this is useful if one time starts before the other
              for j in range(1, len(x2)-1):  
                  x1.append(x2[0])

         #if the x1 array contains more than 1 value
         #add a copy of the previous x1 record to correspond
         #to the new x2 record
         if len(x1) > 0:
              x1.append(x1[len(x1)-1])

 #combine the records
 new__df = pd.DataFrame({'Type 1':x1, 'Type 2': x2})
 #compute the ratio
 new_df['Ratio'] = new_df['x1']/f_df['x2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two dataframes on time and then calculate ratios

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'time', how = 'outer')
new_df['ratio'] = new_df['x values_x'] / new_df['x values_y']
```

You get

```
    time    x values_x  x values_y  ratio
0   1       11          11          1.000000
1   2       12          21          0.571429
2   2       12          12          1.000000
3   3       13          43          0.302326
```

Comment: The problem is that I simplified my example, so time does not actually align between the two frames - they have different dates

Comment: Oh then what would be the basis of finding the ratio?

Comment: I essentially just need to get ratios for any "updated" values. So if you think of time as linear, any time I have an x value associated with a new time period, I need to update the ratio calculation. So I'm tracking how the ratio changes over time. I realize now I set up my example a bit incorrectly.

Comment: @mildlyillogical You should provide a reproducible example

Comment: I may have found a solution, I will post it in a little bit.